# global name NAME is not defined PYTHON

Tags: python

I have problems with the following code, it says "NameError: global name 'Teater' is not defined" I can not solve it by myself...

```
teaterLista = []
lista = []
class Teater:


    def __init__(self, teaterNamn, plats, pensionar,vuxen,barn):
        self.teaterNamn = teaterNamn
        self.plats = plats
        self.pensionar = pensionar
        self.vuxen = vuxen
        self.barn = barn

    def readData():
        #x = Teater(x,teaterNamn, plats,pensionar,vuxen,barn)
        dataFile = open('c:/Teater.txt','r')
        for line in dataFile:
            if(line != '\n'):
                  temp = line.split('=',1)[1]
                  lista.append(temp.strip()) #strip tar bort radavslut

        x = Teater(x,lista[0],lista[1],lista[2],lista[3],lista[4])
    #teaterLista[0] = x
    #print(teaterLista[0])

    readData()
```

Comment: x = Teater(x,lista[0],lista[1],lista[2],lista[3],lista[4])
That line fails, im trying to create a new isntance of Teater with the given parameters.

Comment: Does calling `readData` outside of the `Teater` class work? You might have to do some refactoring to do this -- the `readData` method may not belong in that class reading multiple `Teater`s on an instance of one

Comment: No, the readData does not work outside the class. "name 'readData' is not defined".
Do you think it will work if I make a main method and reads data from there?

Comment: What do you actually intend to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1):

You call `readData()` during class definition. In Python a class body is executed during its definition in the contex of the class definition just as normal code would be. As the class is not completely defined at that moment, you cannot create a new instance, yet, thus get the error.

Dedent the whole definition for `readData` and the following line so all this is executed *after* the definition of the class has completed. This makes `readLine` a module-level function, not a class method. This is typical for a factory function.

```
teaterLista = []
lista = []
class Teater:

    def __init__(self, teaterNamn, plats, pensionar,vuxen,barn):
        self.teaterNamn = teaterNamn
        self.plats = plats
        self.pensionar = pensionar
        self.vuxen = vuxen
        self.barn = barn

def readData():
    #x = Teater(x,teaterNamn, plats,pensionar,vuxen,barn)
    dataFile = open('c:/Teater.txt','r')
    for line in dataFile:
        if(line != '\n'):
              temp = line.split('=',1)[1]
              lista.append(temp.strip()) #strip tar bort radavslut

    x = Teater(lista[0],lista[1],lista[2],lista[3],lista[4])
#teaterLista[0] = x
#print(teaterLista[0])

readData()
```

Note: `x = Teater(x, ...` will not work, as `x` is not defined for the first invocation. If you think about specifying this for the `self` argument: no need; this is done implicitly. You should read how classes work in the documentation/tutorial.

You have to be careful in Python to correctly indent your code, as that defines the block scope.

Comment: if I Dedent that line it says, "NameError: name 'readData' is not defined"

Comment: @user2432626: Yes, I made a mistake in my text. You have to dedent the whole function definition. So that it is not part of the class definition.

Comment: @Olaf are you definitely sure about the impossibility of referring to the class within itself? Please see/try the code in my answer.

Comment: @Pynchia: Problem is OP's intention is not completely clear. However, Your code calls the method after the class _definition_ is completed. You create a new object, then invoke the method. OP's code does not include `self` in the argument list (but he does for `__init__`) of `readData`, so I assume he does not want it to be a method, but a normal function. As he wrote it, `readData` would be called diring class definition, then try to create an object of the unfinished class. Well, in Python a lot works, but I do not think that this is his intention.

Comment: OK, right. Then it's unclear when he calls `readData`. I've removed that bit from my answer.

Comment: @Pynchia: A static method would require the decorator. And a class method decorator and `cls` argument.

Comment: yes, of course. I've removed my answer altogether. OP's intentions are too fuzzy. Good night

Comment: Thnx, your help with your code solved my problem. I rly need to learn this indenting thing. Newbie programmer in python, it differs so much from java,c,c++,c# etc.

Comment: @user2432626: Glad I could help. If you get deeper into Python, you will appreciate it more and more; a good idea is to use the interactive interpreter to "play with the language and test things. If my answer helped, please consider accepting/upvoting. This is the normal way to say "thank you" here. No need for an explicit comment.